# Why is \n appended to filename in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why does this shell script add a return to the filename of the output file?

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/tail -n 1 /path/logchanged.csv >> "/path/logcontatenated.csv"
```

The filename is not called "logcontatenated.csv", but "logcontatenated.csv

"

I really can't find on the internet why this happens.

Comment: What makes you think it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you created that script using Windows? If the line ends in `\r\n` without trailing spaces the file name is interpreted as `logcontatenated.csv\r`. Try `hd yourscript.sh` to display a hexdump of your script. Line breaks should be only a single byte of `0a` rather than two bytes of `0d 0a`, i.e. make sure the byte before any `0a` is NOT `0d`. You could use `dos2unix yourscript.sh` to fix your script. You might need to install `dos2unix` first.

EDIT: Replaced `0c` with `0d`.

Comment: He protected with quotes so probably not. Btw cr is 0d not 0c. This answer should be a comment.

Comment: The quotes don't matter. If you have `"foo""bar"` or `"foo"bar` in a script, it will be interpret as `foobar` in either case. The same applies if you replace `bar` with `\r`.
PS: I never really see `\r` in ascii, sorry.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with your \r hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, `echo -en '#!/bin/bash\r\necho foo > "bar"\r\n' > test` and than `bash ./test` will create a file called `bar\r` containing `foo\n`.

Comment: You should add this comment to your answer.